# Material Swipe To Dismiss in Compose marks incorrect items for dismissal

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm implementing drag/swipe to dismiss functionality in a simple notepad app implemented in Compose. I've run into a strange issue where SwipeToDismiss() in a LazyColumn dismisses not only the selected item but those after it as well.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with SwipeToDismiss()? (I'm aware that it's marked ExperimentalMaterialApi)

I've used the Google recommended approach from here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#swipetodismiss

this is where it happens:

```
/* ...more code... */
LazyColumn {
        items(items = results) { result ->
            Card {
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState()

                //for some reason the dismmissState is EndToStart for all the
                //items after the deleted item, even adding new items becomes impossible
                if (dismissState.isDismissed(EndToStart)) {
                    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                    scope.launch {
                        dismissed(result)
                    }
                }
                SwipeToDismiss(
                    state = dismissState,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp),
    /* ...more code... */
```

and here is my project with the file in question
https://github.com/davida5/ComposeNotepad/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/anotherday/day17/ui/NotesList.kt

Comment: Kindly add `key` to `items` and check if it solves your issue. If not, update the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `key` for the `LazyColumn`'s `items`.

> By default, each item's state is keyed against the position of the
> item in the list. However, this can cause issues if the data set
> changes, since items which change position effectively lose any
> remembered state.

**Example**

```
LazyColumn {
    items(
        items = stateList,
        key = { _, listItem ->
            listItem.hashCode()
        },
    ) { item ->
        // As it is ...
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)